# How do i get numpy select to recognize my column variables?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I ran a decision tree and want to mark each bin by it's prediction. I pulled the unique predictions out of the prediction object like so with the following ouptut.

```
test_df3_dummies['dt_predictions'].unique()
array([0.00617504, 0.00834542, 0.02429166, 0.01016155, 0.00258616,
       0.44985403, 0.05977463, 0.08333904])
```

So I did the following to make a column of bins based on the predictions:

```
condition = [(test_df3_dummies['dt_predictions'] == 0.00617504)
            ,(test_df3_dummies['dt_predictions'] == 0.00834542)
            ,(test_df3_dummies['dt_predictions'] == 0.02429166)
            ,(test_df3_dummies['dt_predictions'] == 0.01016155)
            ,(test_df3_dummies['dt_predictions'] == 0.00258616)
            ,(test_df3_dummies['dt_predictions'] == 0.44985403)
            ,(test_df3_dummies['dt_predictions'] == 0.05977463)
            ,(test_df3_dummies['dt_predictions'] == 0.08333904)]

replace = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

test_df3_dummies['dt_bins'] = np.select(condition, replace, default = 0)
```

But it's not picking up the value.  Pandas cuts off the last two digits so i tried doing that and it also failed.  Is there a trick with `float64` variable types and `np.select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `factorize`:

```
test_df3_dummies = test_df3_dummies.sort_values('dt_predictions')
enum, codes = test_df3_dummies['dt_predictions'].factorize()


test_df3_dummies['dt_bins'] = enum
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
#test_df3_dummies=test_df3_dummies.sort_values('dt_predictions')  #if is neccesary
test_df3_dummies['dt_bins']=test_df3_dummies.groupby('dt_predictions').ngroup + 1
```